# RF output impedance on ESP8684 series

Tags: circuit-design, rf, impedance, impedance-matching

I'm looking for the output impedance on the RF pin of the ESP8684 SOCs.
On other application note like for the ESP32-C3 it mentioned that the output impendance of the RF pin is 35 + 10j.
But for the ESP8684 this is note clearly mentionned on the [circuit design guide](https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/esp8684_hardware_design_guidelines_en.pdf).
The only section I found is :

> ESP8684 series of chips, it is recommended to set the S11 parameter in the figure below to 35+j0 and the center frequency is 2442 MHz.
> [image]

I don't have a network analyzer, so my question is whether I can design a matching circuit based on this value ?

Comment: S11 is the reflection coefficient. If you know the antenna (or load, in general) complex impedance then you can calculate the source impedance.

Comment: I found this formula on the internet ZL = Zo*(1+Γ)/(1-Γ) Where Zo is the source characteristic impedance, Γ the reflection coefficient and ZL the load impedance.
 
So if I take Γ= 0.31 (the datasheet says S11 <= -10dB and I just converted it to a linear value) and a 50 ohm antenna at the same frequency, I find a source impedance of 26.33 ohms. Can I assume that this value corresponds to the output RF impedance pin of the ESP? And why is parameter S11 equal to 35+j0 on the datasheet?

Comment: Probably not. The "S11 less than -10dB" thing is for antenna testing (the setup to the right) to measure and, if necessary, do tuning/matching for the antenna. That is, if you have an antenna of which the impedance is unknown (or you are unsure about it), you can determine it with a network analyser. You don't have access to a network analyser so these might be useless for you. So, at the moment, all you can do is place a CLC (aka PI) network next to the ANT pin of the chip and do the layout with 50 Ohm traces as the design guide suggests (p.16 onwards). Start with C's unfitted & L=0 Ohm, and

Comment: ... test transmission and reception. Trial & error might sound like a terrible idea here, but the correct method is to use a network analyser yet you don't have any. Also, since ESP8684 appears to be a cheaper version of ESP32 (i.e. ESP32-C2 = 8684) of which the output impedance is known as 30~40 ± j10 Ohms (though the packaging brings a slight difference so keep that in mind), it might be a good starting point to copy an existing matching network and tune if necessary, depending on the transmission/reception tests.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the feedback, as I don't have a network analyzer and would like a solution that is more likely to work directly, I think I'll just switch to a version where the output impedance is given.